# Elastic Search ignoring <u> tag

Tags: elasticsearch

I am executing below ES query using java :

```
query = 2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~

    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("XYZ")
    .setTypes("MYTYPE")
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString(query))
    .setFrom((start-1)*.SEARCH_RESULT_PERPAGE).setSize(SEARCH_RESULT_PERPAGE)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();

    SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
```

just cos of this `<u>asasas</u>` I got exception

```
Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1,
column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"];
```

Here is the full exception

```
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[Q702PZY9Ramp-_zZE4hNew][titan][0]: SearchParseException[[titan][0]: from[0],size[2]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":2,"query":{"query_string":{"query":"2bU: \"70501\" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[titan] Failed to parse query [2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~': Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; }{[Q702PZY9Ramp-_zZE4hNew][titan][1]: SearchParseException[[titan][1]: from[0],size[2]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":2,"query":{"query_string":{"query":"2bU: \"70501\" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[titan] Failed to parse query [2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~': Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; }{[Q702PZY9Ramp-_zZE4hNew][titan][2]: SearchParseException[[titan][2]: from[0],size[2]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":2,"query":{"query_string":{"query":"2bU: \"70501\" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[titan] Failed to parse query [2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~': Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; }{[Q702PZY9Ramp-_zZE4hNew][titan][3]: SearchParseException[[titan][3]: from[0],size[2]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":2,"query":{"query_string":{"query":"2bU: \"70501\" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[titan] Failed to parse query [2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~': Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; }{[Q702PZY9Ramp-_zZE4hNew][titan][4]: SearchParseException[[titan][4]: from[0],size[2]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"from":0,"size":2,"query":{"query_string":{"query":"2bU: \"70501\" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~"}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[titan] Failed to parse query [2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~]]; nested: ParseException[Cannot parse '2bU: "70501" AND 2c2: <u>asasas</u>~': Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; nested: TokenMgrError[Lexical error at line 1, column 37.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "/u>~"]; }]
```

Comment: So, If you can encode query string as url, then will it help? try encoding with http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ .. or libraries in java.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the section of reserved characters here:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

There you can find that a / is a reserved character that needs to be escaped. Try the following:

```
<\/u>
```